# Open source js-kit/disqus like tool

Tags: service, comments

is there any open-source and extendable tool like what js-kit/disqus provides that could be self hosted ?

Answer (score 0):

Since disqus is made with django, IMHO it is relevant to suggest something similar that is made with django too. :-) From my understanding is disqus is basically a threaded commenting system. The most popular ones in django community for this is [django-threaded-comments](http://github.com/ericflo/django-threadedcomments/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Juvia](https://github.com/phusion/juvia)

It's in Ruby and there is a demo available following the Github project readme